# Cannot make a generic item in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, generics, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make the following line of code generic:

```
val newItem: Item = documentChange.document.toObject<Item>(Item::class.java)
```

Works fine. However, when I try to make it generic:

```
val addedItem: T = documentChange.document.toObject<T>(T::class.java)
```

Android Studio is complaining:

> Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48SSw.png)

How can I make it generic?

Comment: In kotlin, for generics where you want to access class, you had to mark it as a reified type and that too in an inline function. I suggest watching this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xj45hobMI78).

Comment: @AkshayNandwana Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a function [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) and add [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) keyword to the generic parameter:

```
inline fun <reified T> someFun() {
    //...
    val addedItem: T = documentChange.document.toObject<T>(T::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: If you have time, maybe you can also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642880/how-to-use-i-as-reified-type-parameter-in-a-livedatai-class).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for getting the document in a generic way

```
    inline fun <reified T> getDocumentItemByName(directory: String, crossinline returnResult: (result : T) -> Unit) {

        firestore.collection(directory).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                OnSuccessListener<QueryDocumentSnapshot> { documentSnapshot ->

                    var entity = documentSnapshot.toObject<T>(T::class.java)
                    returnResult(entity)

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
    }
```