# How to use 'I' as reified type parameter in a LiveData<I> class?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, generics, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use generics when subclassing a `LiveData<I> class`. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62637538/9941990), I have tried this:

```
class ItemLiveData<I>(): LiveData<I>() {

    override fun onEvent(querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
        if (e != null) return

        for (documentChange in querySnapshot!!.documentChanges) {
            when (documentChange.type) {
                DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> setValue(getItem(documentChange)) //Add to LiveData
            }
        }
    
    private inline fun <reified I> getItem(doc: DocumentChange) = doc.document.toObject<I>(I::class.java)
}
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot use 'I' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

Check this [printscreen](https://i.ibb.co/1qK0ftG/Screenshot-2020-06-29-19-38-27.png).

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class's `I` type cannot be reified, and so you can't create an overloaded reified `I` for that function. I think you can manually reify the class type by making the class a constructor parameter. Like this:

```
class ItemLiveData<I>(private val type: Class<I>): LiveData<I>() {

    override fun onEvent(querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
        if (e != null) return

        for (documentChange in querySnapshot!!.documentChanges) {
            when (documentChange.type) {
                DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> setValue(getItem(documentChange)) //Add to LiveData
            }
        }
    
    private fun getItem(doc: DocumentChange) = doc.document.toObject<I>(type)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try and get back to you.